# Google FCM ios-quickstart error on click local notification - unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, firebase, localnotification, firebase-notifications

After push message from Google Firebase Console, The push message notification show on top of iPhone device and then I click the message and Xcode throws exception as below:

```
 [UIConcreteLocalNotification setAlertTitle:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17e1a810

 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIConcreteLocalNotification setAlertTitle:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

here this code:

```
//show notification to status bar
UILocalNotification *local_notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

local_notification.userInfo = userInfo;
local_notification.alertBody = userInfo[@"notification"][@"body"];
local_notification.alertTitle = userInfo[@"notification"][@"title"] ? userInfo[@"notification"][@"title"]: @"VietAir.tv Thông báo";
local_notification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0]; // todo item due date (when notification will be fired). immediately here

 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:local_notification];
```

Please help me, thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is while setting the title. 
Check whether it has `alertTitle` method implemented or not. 
Check once the title format you are setting for it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you helped me fix my problem. alertTitle method not implement